# Vimeodotnet UploadEntireFileAsync function not working

Tags: .net, vimeo-api

When I am calling the function UploadEntireFileAsync I am getting developer message saying "developer_message":"The streaming approach is no longer functional. It's after the new update on vimeo recently. Anybody have same error?

vimeoClient.UploadEntireFileAsync(videoFile, 128 * 1048576, null)).Result => giving error instead should upload file.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Feroz, I am using version 2.0.0.23.

Answer (score 1):

In July 2023, Vimeo officially terminated support for the "streaming approach," as previously mentioned in their release documentation back in 2018. This issue has been addressed and resolved in their recent release.

To ensure compatibility, I recommend updating your NuGet package to version V3.2.3 or the latest available version.